# What is the plane of polarisation of light in YDSE?

Tags: optics, double-slit-experiment, interference, polarization, diffraction

I have heard that only polarised light give the interference fringes which are observable. But while doing Young's double slit experiment (YDSE) there is no polariser used, so how the light coming out of the two slits is polarised, and what is the plane of polarisation in this experiment? Similarly there is also no polariser used in Fraunhofer and Fresnel's diffraction then how the light is polarised there?

Comment: Where did you hear "only polarised light" gives interference pattern? Might be a coherent source which is necessary for this purpose.

Comment: Polarization is not important in the double slit interference. Both poarization separately give the effect, and do not interefere with each other.

Comment: I heard that polarised light give interference pattern which are observable.  And since we add the amplitudes of the waves from slits scalarly it means that they are in same plane, otherwise we would have to consider the angle between the plane of vibration also.

Comment: @ronakjain But say every ~microsecond the polarization changes direction, will it matter? The answer is no - you can have some randomly changing polarization, but the thing that is important for interference *coherence*

Comment: A photon is (or is associated with) an electromagnetic wave packet of finite size.  In a double slit experiment a part of that packet emerges from each slit, and the two parts (which are coherent with each other) interfere with each other to produce the probability pattern. An incoming beam of billions of photons, of random phase and polarization, does not need to be coherent.  Young observed interference long before the invention of the laser.

Comment: @R.W.Bird The wave splitting up is nice theory but certainly not proven or the only possible theory. I like Feynman ... each photon takes a probable path n multiples of its wavelength thus some paths are probable and others not. Young needed to apply a pinhole to the light before the slits ... this increases coherence so the pattern is visible to the eye. Interestingly all light has some level of coherence even sunlight.

Comment: I'm thinking that a pinhole would give nearly plane waves arriving at the slits, but would not affect the phase difference between one photon and another.